# Place Autocomplete for autocomplete textview

Tags: android

I'm trying to give auto suggestion for places when user typing in auto complete text view in android. Right now i'm using the new Google play services libraries and sample code from the following link [Place Auto complete](https://developers.google.com/places/android/autocomplete) . But When trying to give suggestion for the user typed text, I'm getting the following error

> Error getting autocomplete prediction API call:
>
> Status { statusCode = NETWORK_ERROR, resolution = null }

Any idea what may be the problem?

Comment: You problem is NETWORK_ERROR.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this: "public static final int  NETWORK_ERROR 
A network error occurred. Retrying should resolve the problem. 
Constant Value:   7 (0x00000007) " see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#NETWORK_ERROR).